# Random variable $X$ it is distributed evenly over the segment $[-\pi, 0]$. Find the distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I don't know what to do in the task:

> Random variable $X$ it is distributed evenly over the segment $[-\pi, 0]$. Find the distribution >function of a random value $Y = \sin X$

I do the following $F_Y = P(\sin X < x) = P(X < -\pi - \arcsin x)$

But then I got stuck, how do I get the information I need from the distribution of X. But I also get that $Im Y = [-1, 0]$ it's mean that function of distribution $0$ on $(-\infty, -1]$ and $1$ on $[0, +\infty)$

Comment: p.d.f. of $X$ is $1/\pi $ on$ [-\pi,0] $ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @user What is p.d.f and Why is $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF (cumulative distribution function) of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb P(X<x)=\frac{x+\pi}{\pi}\,,\quad x\in[-\pi,0]\,.
$$
The PDF (probability distribution function) is the derivative of this.

To find the CDF of $\sin X$ you calculate $\mathbb P(\sin X<x)\,.$ But you made a mistake.

Taking into account that $\sin x$ is symmetric around $-\pi/2$
in the interval $[-\pi,0]$ this is not hard:

> \begin{align}\mathbb P(\sin X<x)&=\mathbb P\Big(-\pi-\arcsin x< X<\arcsin x\Big)\\&=\frac{\arcsin x+\pi}{\pi}-\frac{-\arcsin x}{\pi}=\frac{2\arcsin x+\pi}{\pi}\,.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer!